# Multiple Filtering DataFrame in Python to Use PyQt5 app

Tags: python, dataframe, pyqt5, filtering

```
self.myDataFrame = pd.read_csv("myCSV.csv")

def filterValues(self):
    if self.h02_1_lineEdit != "":
        self.h02_1_flag = 1
        self.filter_h02_1 = (self.myDataFrame['H:02-1'] == self.h02_1_lineEdit.text())
    else:
        self.h02_1_flag = 0

    if self.h02_x_lineEdit != "":
        self.h02_x_flag = 1
        self.filter_h02_x = (self.myDataFrame['H:02-X'] == self.h02_x_lineEdit.text())
    else:
        self.h02_x_flag = 0

    # it will take 6 filters in here
    print(self.myDataFrame[self.filter_h02_1 & self.filter_h02_x])
```

Hello fellas, I've basic application in Python with DF to use on PyQt5 application. As you can see, I read some datas from csv files. And I want to filter some values according to text written on QLineEdit. However, If QLineEdit is empty, I dont want to filter it. But I couldnt figure out how to. On other applications, I can (and I did) solve this issue by using flags. i.e Sql apps. But in that apps, we use query as strings. So that was easy to use.

My real problem here is MULTIPLE FILTERING, again if every line edit (6 line edit I used) or one line edit filtered there is no problem. But, For example, I dont want to use ***self.filter_h02_x*** and leave it as empty. Now this is where I stuck. If needed I can upload all code, but I guess you understand the problem.

To clearify my question;
If we can use ***self.myDataFrame*** as string I can use

```
self.mainFilter = "self.myDataFrame["  # for definition
...
self.filter_h02_1 = "(self.myDataFrame['H:02-1'] == self.h02_1_lineEdit.text())"
...
if self.h02_1_flag = 1:
     self.myDataFrame += self.filter_h02_1 + "]"
print(self.mainFilter)
```

But this is not string, this is definition. If I try to define it one by one there are 6! options...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want to filter you can use a mask of all `True`s

```
if self.h02_1_lineEdit.text() != "":
    self.filter_h02_1 = (self.myDataFrame['H:02-1'] == self.h02_1_lineEdit.text())
else:
    self.filter_h02_1 = [True] * len(myDataFrame)
```

Comment: Unfortunaletly, it returned nothing again. But I got your point, this is what I was looking for "masking" . I'll try a bit more about this logic

Comment: If you need I can post all code and csv file by a link

Comment: No need to, it'll work if you use it on all lineedits and then use `self.myDataFrame[self.filter_h02_1 & self.filter_h02_x & etc....]` to filter. If you still get errors or not the desired result it's caused by something else.

Comment: You were right, my if condition was like
`if self.h02_1_lineEdit`
but true condition is;
`if self.h02_1_lineEdit.text() `
basic mistake :)
thank you again

Comment: You're welcome. I'll update the if condition in the answer just in case.